# Prepending vs. Appending $PATH

Tags: linux, path

I've been installing some software to a new VM today, and started wondering about the PATH variable. Some of the installation scripts I poked through would append to $PATH, and others would prepend $PATH. Personally, I've always just appended whenever I've needed to add to it.

Is there any functional difference between the two techniques, or is it just personal preference? My gut feeling is that it shouldn't make any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: If duplicate programs exist the one that appears first in the path will be used over the latter.